# Parsing JSON data ASP.NET C# and Razor

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hi I'm working in VS with ASP.NET and razor, trying to fill a table with values from a db table but I have to decode or parse Json to simple text. I really appreciate some help.
This is what i´m getting.
[image]

```html
  [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetData()
        {
            string stdb = "Data Source=DMX87025;Initial Catalog=DB_PCC;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(stdb);
            string sql = "SELECT *FROM[DB_PCC].[dbo].[Departments]";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            conn.Open();

            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            var st = "kyo please help me u.u";
            return Json(new { success = true, message = rd },
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

This is my AJAX ...

```js
<div id="result"></div>
<input type="button" name="name" value="try" onclick="DepListQuery()" />

<script>

    function DepListQuery() {


        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetData","Home")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {

                $('#result').text(response.message);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("something get wrong u.u");
            }
        });
    }

    

</script>
```

Comment: Your need to read the data after `ExecuteReader()` and convert to a model and return a collection of that model, then loop through the collection in your script.

Comment: `SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();` You then set `message = rd`. You need to do `rd.Read()` to get the strings.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to fix is how you read data from the `SqlDataReader`. Here is a tutorial on doing so: http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson04

But even better would be to read data directly into objects. See this answer for details on creating such extension methods: [Convert rows from a data reader into typed results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202935/convert-rows-from-a-data-reader-into-typed-results)

The sample extension method:

```
public static List<T> ReadList<T>(this IDataReader reader, 
                                  Func<IDataRecord, T> generator) {
     var list = new List<T>();
     while (reader.Read())
         list.Add(generator(reader));
     return list;
}
```

After your `SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();` line, you'd need something like:

```
var departmentList = reader.ReadList(x => new Department {
                                           DeptID = x.GetInt32(0),
                                           DeptName = x.GetString(1)
                                    });
```

Then, once you have such a list of objects, you can return them to the front-end view ajax:

[How to parse JSON list of string on ajax return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34266884/how-to-parse-json-list-of-string-on-ajax-return)

[List of Objects To Json String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26771869/list-of-objects-to-json-string)

I also want to note that you should surround your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataReader`, etc with `using` blocks.

Comment: you could post a more explicit example i'm new on asp.net and C# so kind get lost ...